Hasse principle for quadratic forms vs algebraic groups
Can the Hasse-Minkowski theorem for quadratic forms over a number field be recovered from the Hasse principle for algebraic groups? More specifically, by the former I mean the theorem that two quadratic forms over a number field $K$ are equivalent if they are equivalent over all places, and by the latter I mean the statement that if $G$ is a simply connected semisimple algebraic group over $K$, then the natural map $H^1(K, G)\rightarrow \prod_v H^1(K_v, G)$ is injective.
This is probably well-known, but I was unable to find a reference.
